# Using php Code in .html or .htm files

Tags: php, apache

I've added the line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

to my Apache Config file, but I still fail to get php scripting inside an .html file to parse. What am I doing wrong?

Is this the wrong config file for adding this information into?

Comment: How this is related to 'windows-8'?

Comment: Well, **which** config file specifically did you put it in? If `httpd.conf`, did someone forget to restart the server?

Comment: Yes, please remove the windows 8 tag; perhaps add the apache tag - tagging correctly may get you more answers as the people following those tags are more likely to see the question. Did you restart Apache after making the changes to the config?

Comment: Did you install the PHP module?

Comment: Why are you wanting to put PHP in a HTML file? Either put HTML in a PHP file, or use `.htaccess` and a `RewriteRule` to “mask” the file extension if you don’t want to promote the fact you’re using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$.html $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$.htm $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The handler used can vary a bit.

I would recommend passing through a PHP file as a last resort since this can be solved with less effort, which is one brute-force approach.

Some of the highly common variations are below but there may be more.

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php

    AddType application/x-httpd-php5

    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php

    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5
```

As also mentioned, a combination of both AddType and AddHandler may be required.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you quest, but you can fake that is a HTML file the user call by use the Apache RewriteEngine as like this.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^((.+)\.(html|htm))$ ($2).php [L]
```

I also think this is a good security point to not run `.html` as a PHP script if you forget 
you has config this or the use can upload HTML to you server. 
( Not config apache to run file on the filesytem with `.html` as PHP files. )

Answer (score 1):

Some web hosts require both directives. Try this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php  .htm .html
```

If you do not require this for your entre site would also strongly suggest using .htaccess to do this on a per file / directory basis.